# Java lambda sublist

Tags: java, collections, lambda, java-8, java-stream

What is the shortest way to express "get new List B from List A where condition" via a Java 8 lambda?

Say I have `List<Integer> a = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` and I want a new List, B, where the value is > 3.

I've read through the new Collections Streams API, but I'm not convinced I have found the best way to do this, and don't want to taint the question with what is probably my less than perfect solution.

Comment: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/java-8-lambda-walkthrough.html#highlighter_349693

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
a.stream().filter(x -> x > 3).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

## Java 16 solution

It can be written in a further shorter form in [JDK 16 which includes a toList() method directly on Stream instances](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8180352).

```
a.stream().filter(x -> x > 3).toList();
```

Comment: I just love SO - one answer; and straight from one of the Guava guys! Does it get any better?