# How do I split a collection into subcollections?

Tags: java, list, collections

I have a List of Users, who have a name and an age. I would like to split this list into sublists, where each list contains all the users with a particular age.

Here's some code for an example:

```
public class User{
    public String name;
    public int age;
}

User user1 = new User();
user1.setName("Tom");
user1.setAge("20");

User user2 = new User();
user2.setName("Jack");
user2.setAge("21");

User user3 = new User();
user3.setName("Peter");
user3.setAge("21");

List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
userList.add(user1);
userList.add(user2);
userList.add(user3);
```

How can I can split `userList` so List1 (holding users age 20) contains Tom
and List2(holding users age 21) contains Jack and Peter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to create a `Map<Integer, List<User>>` which will map ages to lists of users.

```
Map<Integer, List<User>> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, List<User>>();
for (User u: userList) {
   if (!myMap.containsKey(u.age)) myMap.put(u.age, new ArrayList<User>());
   myMap.get(u.age).add(u);
}
```

If you then want to iterate over them and print it out, you can iterate over the Map like this.

```
for (Integer i : myMap.keySet()) {
    System.out.print(i + ": ");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (User u: myMap.get(i))
       sb.append("," + u.name);
    System.out.println(sb.toString().substring(1)); // Remove the first comma
}
```

Output:

```
21: Jack,Peter
20: Tom
```

Note that if you had wanted the `Map` to iterate in order by `age`, you can replace `HashMap` with `TreeMap` above, with the realization that your insertions and accesses will be `O(log n)` instead of `O(1)`.

Comment: he wants different lists for different age

Comment: @VD', I just changed it.

Answer (score 1):

Use Map with key age and value User List as follows

```
Map<Integer,List<User>> userMap = new HashMap<Integer,List<User>>();

Then, whenever you want to add a new age you put a new empty list and
public void addNewAge(Integer age) {
    userMap.put(age, new ArrayList<User>());
}

When you want to add a user, you obtain the user list based on the age represented by a Integer.
public void addUserToList(Integer age, User user) {
    if(userMap.containsKey(age))
        userMap.get(age).add(user);        
}
```

make little more look on Map So that it will comfort for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java 8, you could use lambda's for this as explained in this post -> [Java lambda sublist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577824/java-lambda-sublist)

If you're not using java 8, then I would also go with a Map implementation holding the age as key and the list as value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Streams API to do this, you can use the GroupingBy collector:

```
Map<Integer, List<User>> groupedByAge = users.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy((u)->u.age));

List<User> age20 = groupedByAge.get(20); // contains Tom
List<User> age21 = groupedByAge.get(21); // contains Jack, Peter
```

If you want all users over a certain age, and they're not conveniently all the same age, you can either collect from the map, or you can change your groupingBy function to this:

```
Map<Boolean, List<User>> groupedByAge = users.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy((u)->u.age>20));

List<User> ageUnder21 = groupedByAge.get(false);
List<User> age21AndOver = groupedByAge.get(true);
```